# Getting number of total MPI bytes transferred by a program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Is there any way in MPI to get the total number of bytes transferred by my entire MPI program in C?

Comment: Have you considered using an external tool and or profiling library? Something like ITAC or MPIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of directly, but you could adapt the following code to your purposes:

```
uint64_t bytes_recv = 0;

void CommRecv(MyObject* a){
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

  int msg_size;
  MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_BYTE, &msg_size);
  bytes_recv += msg_size;

  // Allocate a buffer to hold the incoming data
  char* buf = (char*)malloc(msg_size);
  assert(buf!=NULL);

  MPI_Recv(buf, msg_size, MPI_BYTE, from, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

  //Do stuff

  free(buf);
}
```

The point here is to wrap the standard MPI communication functions with functions that keep track of data transfer statistics. Internally, these functions use `MPI_Get_count()` to retrieve the size of the incoming message. This is then added to a global variable that tracks communication over all of the wrapped MPI functions.

At the end of the program you can accumulate each instance's global variables on the master process.

Comment: Hi, I am new to MPI programming but I think only the bytes_recv will do the job for my case right. I won't need the extra MPI_recv or does it do anything significant.

Comment: No, the extra `MPI_recv` does not do anything significant. You may still find it useful, though, as it allows you to use e.g. `My_MPI_Recv` anywhere in your code without having to make byte-counting modifications.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use a MPI profiling tool such as the simple [mpiP](http://mpip.sourceforge.net). There are more sophisticated / heavyweight tools that can also do that, such as Score-P. You should check if there is something available if you are running your code on an HPC site.